# Google PHP client won't authenticate code, invalid_request

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

I'm using Google PHP Client 4ae272683e18888362e1f935b813e345b99e23b8 pulled Aug 9 from github. I feel like my code is too simple to be wrong.

```
require_once ('Google/Client.php');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
$client->authenticate($_POST['code']);
```

I get this `invalid_request` error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_request'' in /Users/dfabulich/test/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:125
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/dfabulich/test/Google/Client.php(135): Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate('4/58wTCTNiQNIdR...')
#1 /Users/dfabulich/test/google-login.php(24): Google_Client->authenticate('4/58wTCTNiQNIdR...')
#2 {main}
```

`client_secret.json` is the exact file I downloaded from the Google API Developers Console. The file definitely exists, because if I use the wrong file name, I get a very clear error, "Invalid client secret JSON file." I've visually inspected the file and it looks fine.

I edited Google/Auth/OAuth2.php to log the post body as json; it looks like this (but I've HIDDEN the client secret below):

{"code":"4\/58wTCTNiQNIdRfb8DgQBYk518URV.Elrb71kFKHAYEnp6UAPFm0HWWGd6jwI","grant_type":"authorization_code","redirect_uri":"","client_id":"807284957448-3katmu7oqd1277ql9eo258dadkbkqruq.apps.googleusercontent.com","client_secret":"HIDDEN"}

What could I possibly be doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the Google+ Sign-in API, so I also needed to add a `setRedirectUri("postmessage")` line. This code works.

```
require_once ('Google/Client.php');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
$client->authenticate($_POST['code']);
```

Comment: I was struggling with this error as well, and I found that the real key for me was to have the SAME client set* statements that were used before the $client->createAuthUrl(); to be in place before the  $client->authenticate($_POST['code']); call.

Answer (score 1):

I cant tell you why your code doesn't work I have never tried using `setAuthConfigFile` This is the code i use

```
<?php         
require_once 'Google/Client.php';     
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';       
session_start();      
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("{devkey}");  
    $client->setClientId('{clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('{clientsecret}');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://www.daimto.com/Tutorials/PHP/Oauth2.php');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

    //For loging out.
    if ($_GET['logout'] == "1") {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
       }   

    // Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
    if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
        }        

    // Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);    

        // request user accounts
        $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

       foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {
        echo "Account: ",$item['name'], "  " , $item['id'], "<br /> \n";        
        foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WebProperty: ' ,$wp['name'], "  " , $wp['id'], "<br /> \n";    

            $views = $wp->getProfiles();
            if (!is_null($views)) {
                foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {
                //  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;View: ' ,$view['name'], "  " , $view['id'], "<br /> \n";    
                }
            }
        }
    } // closes account summaries

    }
 print "<br><br><br>";
 print "Access from google: " . $_SESSION['token']; 
?>
```

My tutorial can be found at [Google Oauth2 php](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/)

Comment: I tried something like that, too; no help. (I thought, "Maybe I'm copying and pasting incorrectly?" which is why I tried setAuthConfigFile, which is too simple to screw up.) The only difference I see is that I'm using the G+ login API with no redirect URI (no redirect URI is set in the console) and no scopes. So, comment out the setRedirectUri line and the setScopes line, and that's my code. But it's not working.

Comment: You need a redirect uri or the authentication server doesn't know where to return the code to. That is probably your problem. Scopes are also required.

Comment: I got it to work with "postmessage" as my redirect URI.

Comment: Has anyone any ideas why google doesn't send me back any valid token to start the ball rolling. My system does work on localhost but live which seems identical is not working and $client->getAccessToken() doesn't get an access token but there is no API error either and it does return ok. The access token variable is empty.