# Not getting Google analytics data in PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get analytics data can someone help me, below are the ways I tried but I am getting 500 internal server.

```
<?php
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php');
session_start();   
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("meme");
$client->setDeveloperKey('my app key here');
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$projectId = '103785255';
$from = '2016-01-18'; // 2 days
$to = date('Y-m-d'); // today
$metrics = 'ga:pageviews';
$dimensions = 'ga:date,ga:year,ga:month,ga:day';
$data = $service->data_ga->get('ga:'.$projectId, $from, $to, $metrics, array('dimensions' => $dimensions));
print_r($data);
?>
```

Second method with oauth-2.0 authentication

```
<?php
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php');
session_start();
$client_id = 'my client id .apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = 'my client secret';
$redirect_uri = 'redirect uri';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("meme");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setAccessType("offline");

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);print_r($client);exit;
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !$_SESSION['token']) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    print "<div><a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a></div>";
}

if($_SESSION['token']){
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
  $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
  $projectId = '103785255';
  $_params[] = 'pageviews';
  $from = '2016-01-18'; // 2 days
  $to = date('Y-m-d'); // today

    $metrics = 'ga:pageviews';

    $dimensions = 'ga:date,ga:year,ga:month,ga:day';
    $data = $service->data_ga->get('ga:'.$projectId, $from, $to, $metrics, array('dimensions' => $dimensions));
    foreach($data['totalsForAllResults'] as $row) {
       echo $row;
    }   
}
?>
```

If you see I have placed a print statement after $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); where I am getting 500 internal server error If I print the code before authenticate method it is printing, facing issue while calling $client->authenticate($_GET['code']).  Even followed the below links and endup with the same issues

[Google PHP client won't authenticate code, invalid_request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224300/google-php-client-wont-authenticate-code-invalid-request)

http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

Comment: Which version of google-php-api-client are you using?

Comment: I got the latest google-php-client library from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.

Comment: Did you try the v1 branch? It seems your code is not adapted to v2 yet...

Comment: Can you get me the link to v1 branch.

Comment: Sure, [https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/archive/v1-master.zip](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/archive/v1-master.zip)